# how does the validation split work when calling fit?

Tags: neural-network, keras

When I specify the validation_split parameter when calling the fit method of the model class, is the same validation data used at every epoch? Or does the validation data change for every epoch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the same validation data for every epoch.

If it didn't then it wouldn't be validation data as the model would learn have seen elements in the validation set during previous epochs and and thus would have the possibility of overfitting to them.